# How to add logger in the Azure Worker role?

Tags: c#, .net, azure

The below code is used to bulk insert data into an Azure database.  It does not work properly when hosted in an Azure instance.

```
try
{
  SqlCommand truncate = new SqlCommand("truncate table dbo.Dispatch", connection);
  truncate.Transaction = transaction;
  truncate.ExecuteNonQuery();

  using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, transaction))
  {
    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 100;
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Dispatch";
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dispatch.AsDataTable());
  }

  SqlCommand updateHaulerCode = new SqlCommand("exec [sp_UpdateDispatchHaulerCodes]", connection);
  updateHaulerCode.Transaction = transaction;
  updateHaulerCode.ExecuteNonQuery();
  transaction.Commit();

}
catch (Exception)
{
  transaction.Rollback();
}
```

I want to add logging in the catch statement.

Comment: How does it not 'work properly'?

Comment: Also, please describe how this is hosted in Azure. Is this a webjob, running on a worker role in a Cloud Service or code running in an Azure Virtual Machine.

Comment: It is the webjob running on a worker role in a Cloud Service